# Appending script child to a angular certain angular component

Tags: javascript, angular

I am currently adding an external javascript source to my component using this

**component.ts**

```
this.script = this._renderer2.createElement('script');
this.script.type = 'text/javascript';
this.script.src = url
this.script.async = true;
document.getElementById('scriptContainer').appendChild(this.script);
```

**component.html**

```
<div id='scriptContainer' #scriptContainer></div>
```

And the problem is, it is displaying the script in every page/component in my angular project. I can't destroy the element too

Comment: What do you actually expect to happen? Your script container never dies

Answer (score 0):

Well in terms of script I am not sure if its right to inject it to component.

I do have service which inject scripts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

interface Scripts {
  name: string;
  src: string;
}

declare var document: any;

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class DynamicScriptLoaderService {
  private scripts: any = {};

  constructor() {}

  loadScript(src: string) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (!this.scripts[src]) {
        this.scripts[src] = true;
        //load script
        let script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.src = src;
        if (script.readyState) {
          //IE
          script.onreadystatechange = () => {
            if (script.readyState === 'loaded' || script.readyState === 'complete') {
              script.onreadystatechange = null;
              resolve({ script: src, loaded: true, status: 'Loaded' });
            }
          };
        } else {
          //Others
          script.onload = () => {
            resolve({ script: name, loaded: true, status: 'Loaded' });
          };
        }
        script.onerror = (error: any) => resolve({ script: name, loaded: false, status: 'Loaded' });
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
      } else {
        resolve({ script: name, loaded: true, status: 'Already Loaded' });
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Then in my code i would do

```
 this.scriptoader
      .loadScript(
        '//myscript.com/script.js'
      )
      .then(() => {});
```

THis will make sure that i inject script only once and allow me to execute code after script is loaded